# UIBezierPath roundedRect - change color of corners

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I have a simple rounded rect

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerSize, height: cornerSize))
    fillColor.setFill()
    path.fill()
    //fillColor is set to UIColor.black
    //cornerSize is set to 20
}
```

But the corners are white. If I set background color in UIBuilder to clear color, the rounded rect becomes a rect with sharp corners. I tried to create an oval with rect and fill it with clear color. This also didn't work.
Maybe the answer is trivial but I'm absolutely clueless.

[image]

Comment: There is no other go u need to specify a backgroundColor. I also faces same problem If I give clear color to superview then the superview background color changes to Black

Comment: set gray  as the background color to the view

Comment: There is a TableView in the background. Setting background color gray is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine as it is. If it is drawing solid black when the views background color is clear then that probably means you have a black view of the same size behind your bezier view. You can test this by changing the fill color of your bezier curve to something other than black.

Its a lot easier to debug if you use the @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable keywords:

```
@IBDesignable class BezierView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var fillColor = UIColor.black

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius = 20.0

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
    fillColor.setFill()
    path.fill()
}
```

}

It will then draw the view in the storyboard and you can edit the fill color and corner radius in the views inspector.

Comment: I did that already. I know what the problem is now. The default values of IBInspectable var fillColor and IBInspectable var cornerRadius are ignored when I change background color to clearColor. How can I commit default values to IB? After setting EVERYTHING (fillColor, cornerRadius and BackgroundColor) in IB it works like expected. Thank you!